# Is it possible to host two different Odata models in a Web API service

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to host two different OData models in a single Web API service?
And if so, how can I achieve this?

Ex:
Two Models like,

```
var model1 = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Car>("Car");

var model2 = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Animal>("Animal");
```

Hope it's possible through some sort of routing.

Controllers for `Car` and `Animal`

```
public class AnimalController:ODataController{
 //Implementation stuff
}

public class AnimalController:ODataController{
//Implementation stuff
}
```

And ModelBuilder

```
public class ModelBuilder{
    public static IEdmModel GetModal1(){
        var model1 = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Car>("Car");
        return model1.GetEdmModel();
    }

    public static IEdmModel GetModal2(){
        var model2 = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Animal>("Animal");
        return model2.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Routing for Modal1

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        routeName: "OData",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: ModelBuilder.GetModal1());
    }
}
```

So question again is how do I add modal2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

1-Add the two entity sets into one `Edm` model.

```
public class ModelBuilder
    {
        public static IEdmModel GetModal()
        {
           ODataConventionModelBuilder builder= new ODataConventionModelBuilder(); 
           builder.EntitySet<Car>("Car");
           builder.EntitySet<Animal>("Animal");
           return model.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
```

2- Add two end points for different `Edm` models.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        routeName: "OData1",
        routePrefix: "odata1",
        model: ModelBuilder.GetModal1());

        config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
        routeName: "OData2",
        routePrefix: "odata2",
        model: ModelBuilder.GetModal2());
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should create an `ApiController` for Cars and a separate one for Animals.

Comment: Hi Rik, I do have the `ODataController` for  both `Animal` and `Car` and also added the `modal1` into `config.Routes.MapODataRoute`. what i want to know is how to add `modal2` to `config.Routes.MapODataRoute` Thanks